# AngularJS - change variable value with if else statement when scope changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable that I want to change when another scope changes its value.

```
$scope.switch = true;

var thing;
if ($scope.switch == false) {
    thing = "givesFalse";
}
else {
    thing = "givesTrue";
};
this.thingscope = thing;
```

So when I change `$scope.switch` value to false, `this.thingscope` should output `givesFalse`. In order to change the scope value, I use ng-click:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
    {{myCtrl.thingscope}}
    <br>
    <a ng-click="switch = !switch">{{switch}}</a>   
</div>
```

But even that I can see that the scope does update, the variable `thing` doesn't seem to update at the same time. You can see the working plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FGovwUjEZtaRgkO85S0q?p=preview). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options:

0 - Automatic: Using Watch

```
$scope.$watch('switch', function () {
  $scope.thing = $scope.switch ? "givesTrue" : "givesFalse";
});
```

1 - Manual: Use a custom function which change both values.

```
ng-click="switch = !switch"
```

change it to:

```
ng-click="customFunction()"
```

And define in the controller:

```
$scope.customFunction = function () {
  $scope.switch = !$scope.switch;
  $scope.thing = $scope.switch ? "givesTrue" : "givesFalse";
}
```

Comment: I used the second one and it works perfect (http://plnkr.co/edit/FGovwUjEZtaRgkO85S0q?p=preview) Thanks for the approach!

Comment: Here is a [http://plnkr.co/edit/1DvOpeRsyXEhmQzgE7Nl?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/1DvOpeRsyXEhmQzgE7Nl?p=preview) based on your previous plnkr. With both implementations:

Comment: @joe82 - My recommendation is that you use the $scope.watch method, as that's what it's built for. Let Angular do the majority of the work for you.

Comment: @JoséLezama in the first implementation, how is it suppose to work? I cannot switch it in the plunkr by clicking the switch link

Comment: My bad, I shared with an error. Please check this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/g8iwAHDfzgyNgOM1DNiJ?p=preview

Comment: I mark this as correct as the scope.watch method seem to be more recommended to do it the "angular way". Thanks again!

Comment: @JoséLezama in my real code, instead of text I have two functions as output. See plunker here (http://plnkr.co/edit/F4KTtQ5oOEn9a2LCjICs?p=preview)

What would then be the correct way to do it?

Comment: @Joe82

Check the Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/v8VscDRUhVd0IG0bNYjq?p=preview

Please use $scope instead this (is more Angular Way). I assume you are using lodash (or underscore, I prefer lodash so I include lodash over underscore).

Plus, I didn't find the ng-lodash CDN but you must use for a more elegant code. https://github.com/rockabox/ng-lodash

I use it without problem. 

I just:
- Change this to $scope
- Add the lodash lib.

Comment: @JoséLezama Thanks again, I didn't know about the ng-lodash existence, I will definitely look into it!

Comment: I made a related question to this one as I found a problem when applying it to my code. I leave the link in case is on your interest (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646216/angularjs-scope-watch-with-filtered-scopes-as-output)

Answer (score 1):

The main point is that your Controller's code will be executed only once when your Controller is instanciated.
If you want it to respond to changes, you'll need to use `$watch`.

```
$scope.$watch('switch', function(newSwitchValue, oldSwitchValue) {
  if ($scope.switch == false) {
    $scope.thing = "givesFalse";
  }
  else {
    $scope.thing = "givesTrue";
  }
});
```

In a real-world app where the architecture and performance matters, I would advise you to call directly a function from the *ng-click*.

```
ng-click="onClickSwitch()"
```

Then define the function *onClickSwitch()* in the *$scope*.

```
$scope.onClickSwitch = function() {
    $scope.switch = !$scope.switch;
    [code as above]
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to implement it with my code, as it is slightly different, see updated plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/il5R7L8kOQwkCfPyetA9?p=preview)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/i260kK85zTniDDk3nmVQ?p=preview
Here is a fork without using `$watch`

Comment: I mark it as correct as the answer is more complete and related with my approach. Thanks!