# How to filter objects based on value of key given inside same object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have list of objects where I have to filter the objects based on value of a key present inside same object and create `<div>` tag with content.

List of objects:

```
{
    "statusCode" : 200,
    "statusMessage" : "OK",
    "result" : [
    {
            "owner" : {
                "id" : "3f32ce2f-4300-439b-84bc-92ad46fbccf7"
            },
            "name" : "Test 12345",
            "description" : "Test 12345",
            "created_at" : 1465222538,
            "active" : "true",
            "id" : "2ade9236-c382-400c-9c0b-94e96db9b2aa",
            "status" : "OPEN"
        }, {
            "owner" : {
                "id" : "3f32ce2f-4300-439b-84bc-92ad46fbccf7"
            },
            "name" : "sample2",
            "description" : "sample2",
            "created_at" : 1465117865,
            "active" : "true",
            "id" : "8bf206f9-d3e0-43f4-ba3f-f71c88db9b0e",
            "status" : "IN PROGRESS"
        }, 
    ]
}
```

I want to filter data based on `"status" : "IN PROGRESS"` or `"status" : "OPEN"` and show the data inside `<li>` tag but the thing is identifier(key) is present inside the same object. How do I achieve this in angularjs or vanilla javascript?

For now I am looping using ng-repeat to create and show data in `<li>`:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="wd in currentPageWorkOrders>
            <a ng-click="viewProject(wd)"  href="">
                <h4>{{wd.name}}</h4>
            </a>
            <p>Publisher Name</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filters by Angular in a shorter way.
e.g. You can filter in the ng-repeat.

So, your ng-repeat will be something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="wd in elements | filter:search">
  <a ng-click=" viewProject(wd) " href=" ">
    <h4>{{wd.name}}</h4
  </a>
  <p>Status: {{wd.status}}</p>
</li>
```

Where the search is a new element where you set the fiters elements. In my case I use:

```
<span class="btn btn-default" ng-click="search.status=''">No Filters</span>
<span class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="search.status='OPEN'">Show Open</span>
<span class="btn btn-success" ng-click="search.status='IN PROGRESS'">Show In Progress</span>
```

You can check how it works, in the Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/5V3Rg0lggjnPVFu3srsG?p=preview

Comment: Thank you Jose. How do I provide pagination lets say I want to show only 10 objects on ng-click?

Comment: In that case you will need a second list. With only the filtered elements, and make few maths operations: Have a page, number of pages. You can check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581209/pagination-on-a-list-using-ng-repeat check the Fiddle. It works so good!

And use:  `<li ng-repeat="item in filteredData | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter out the required data

```
var _getResult = myArray[0].result;
var filterArray = _getResult.filter(function(item){
 return item.status ==="OPEN" || item.status === "IN PROGRESS"

})
console.log(filterArray)
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t08e0g3n/)

Comment: How is resultant object different from object I am passing? Its printing the same object out. I want to create `<li`> based on `status` key

Comment: So if the `status == open` I will create a `<li>object data</li>` and if the `status==In progress' then another `<li>object data</li>`

Comment: Hi, one quick question, from where is the item parameter inside function coming from? We just pass it like that? I am from java background

Comment: Instead of wd in currentPageWorkOrders do wd.filterArray, after attaching filter array with scope. filterArray will have only those status that you need

Comment: item is just an argument which array.prototype.filter accepts,instead of item you can name it anything you like

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-if to filter the items.codepen url for reference
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MeaawO

```
  <li ng-repeat="wd in currentPageWorkOrders.result" ng-if="wd.status == 'OPEN'">
                          <a ng-click="viewProject(wd)"  href="">
                              <h4  >{{wd}}</h4>

                          </a>

                      </li>
```

Hope this is helpful for you

Comment: Hi, I have list of button on the sidebar called `<button>OPEN</button>`, `<button>IN PROGRESS</button>` etc. I want to display the above results only when I click on the respective buttons

Comment: Check the updated codepen URL -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MeaawO .Hope this works for you :)